# how to make version variable secure from $_GET

Tags: php

i have `page?vesion=1.0.1`

how can i make $_GET['version'] secure by somthing like

```
$version = (float) $_GET['version'];
```

but this will work if it 1.2 or 1.0 and will not work if its 1.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex such as `/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,3}/` to validate it. [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is your friend:

```
if (preg_match('/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,3}/', $_GET['version'], $match)) {
    // $match[0] contains the validated version number
}
```

I could help you more if I knew exactly what you're trying to accept and what to reject.

edit: replace the 3 in the regex with the number of secondary version numbers; with 3 0.1.2.3 is allowed, but 0.1.2.3.4 is not

Comment: Don't forget `^` and `$` anchors! `2.5.0'; DROP TABLE...` is not a good version number to allow. ;-)

Comment: something like the php version 5.3.0

Comment: @Wiseguy you really should pass your data through mysql_real_escape_query anyway, even if you're totally sure what your variables hold

Comment: Of course. But what if you're using version number in something else, such as a file operation (e.g., `2.5.0; rm -rf /`). The point is to ensure that `$_GET['version']` is a valid version number, which this will not without anchors. It's just a bonus that invalid version strings could also be used maliciously (which I inferred by the asker's desire to "make it secure".

Comment: @Wiseguy, the correct way to use `preg_match` is to get its return value and get the match from `$retval[0]`. This would impair any such attack.

Comment: You could do it that way, too, but please specify that in your answer. Also, there may be additional usefulness in checking the _entire_ string as a version number. If you detect that the incoming string has more than just a version number in it, you may want to log that as evidence of an attack attempt or to reveal an error in the code that passes that value.